# How to delay ManagedScheduledExecutorService until container is not suspended?

Tags: jakarta-ee, scheduler, wildfly-11

I am investigating the use of `javax.enterprise.concurrent.ManagedScheduledExecutorService` on `WildFly Full 11.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 3.0.8.Final)`.

My Startup EJB resembles

```
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.ejb.Startup;
import javax.enterprise.concurrent.ManagedScheduledExecutorService;

@Startup
@Singleton
public class Scheduler {

    static final long INITIAL_DELAY = 0L;
    static final long PERIOD = 2L;

    @Resource
    ManagedScheduledExecutorService scheduler;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        this.scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(this::invokePeriodically, INITIAL_DELAY, PERIOD, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    public void invokePeriodically() {
        System.out.println("@@@@@@@@@@ - Don't use sout in prod " + LocalTime.now());
    }

}
```

On Server Startup I see these messages:-

```
10:15:26,022 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ee] (EE-ManagedScheduledExecutorService-default-Thread-1) WFLYEE0110: 
Failed to run scheduled task: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
WFLYEE0111: Cannot run scheduled task com.research.Scheduler$$Lambda$932/1222053658@1b50d7a0 as container is suspended
    at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ControlPointUtils$ControlledScheduledRunnable.run(ControlPointUtils.java:164)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.concurrent.internal.ManagedScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ManagedScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ManagedScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:383)
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.concurrent.internal.ManagedScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ManagedScheduledFutureTask.run(ManagedScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:534)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.concurrent.ManagedThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThread.run(ManagedThreadFactoryImpl.java:250)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.service.ElytronManagedThreadFactory$ElytronManagedThread.run(ElytronManagedThreadFactory.java:78)
```

When I increase the initial delay

```
static final long INITIAL_DELAY = 60L;
```

The server startup is "clean".

Are there any available mechanisms/techniques I can use (other than guessing how long my initial delay should be) to always get a clean server startup and schedule my EJB as soon as possible?

Comment: Consider using an EJB timer for this purpose instead

Comment: @SteveC for EJB timer I have to use cron values and I am cron averse

Comment: Thats not true - look at [javax.ejb.TimerService](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ejb/TimerService.html)

Comment: @SteveC, I dont know how I managed to miss that option, works well, although on startup seems to fire additional instances. Maybe to do with being persistent (or not?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be better off using an EJB timer for this purpose. The server is guaranteed not to fire timer methods until the EJB is in service.

You can verify the API for creating timers at [javax.ejb.TimerService](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ejb/TimerService.html).

Note that if you create persistent timers then the server will try to "catch up" with missed firings when you restart the server.

If it's just a periodic task then don't create persistent timers.

Comment: @SeveC so far I have only tried TimerService with persistent timers, each time I restart my server I gain an additional timer being triggered. I will investigate TimerConfig to control persistence. Thanks for looking at my issue.

Answer (score 1):

A little late to answer this, but instead of relying on another API, you can use the built in EE annotation: `@Schedule` above your method declaration. It provides the capability to determine timeouts and persistence internally.